# Where did my comment go?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

One of my comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24950972) has disappeared from  the middle of the thread, between [#comment38779006_24950972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950928/is-x-x-always-positive-zero-for-doubles-or-sometimes-negative-zero/24950972#comment38779006_24950972) and [#comment38779349_24950972](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950928/is-x-x-always-positive-zero-for-doubles-or-sometimes-negative-zero/24950972#comment38779349_24950972). It also doesn't appear under Activity in my profile. Where did it go?

Comment: It got flagged and deleted?

Comment: Shouldn't I be notified of that? I have no idea why it would have been.

Comment: I don't think you get notified, I certainly didn't for one of my previous comment a while ago.

Comment: @jtbandes by design you don't get notified. Would be a nice extra feature but I guess the SE team has more important stuff to fix than this bonus.

Comment: it's either an oversight in the design, or intentional by design.. If intentional, perhaps it was planned to be a perk associated to rep, but hasn't made it in.. or perhaps deterring chatty commentators isn't in line with the interest of the system.. It thrives on activity...

@HamZa I disagree with your philosophy to expect less from those who would be accountable under the guise that - since one can't account for what they are considering, have considered, or are actually doing - you can presume it must important.

Comment: @BrettCaswell I do not expect anything. I'm just stating that there are bigger problems to fix than this nice little feature.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "nice feature" but a critical place to inform the community what's going on. Certainly not all "chatty" comments detract value from the community. Regardless, seeing content deleted with no notice or suggestion for improvement makes me uncomfortable. Maybe I'm just spoiled by my 10k privileges.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was flagged and deleted for being too chatty. For whatever reason, comment flaggers have a habit of cherry-picking when flagging comments — if they thought the comment that they flagged was too chatty, then so were at least a few of those leading up to it.

It doesn't help that we don't get an immediate contextual display of comments when looking at comment flags. Only the flagged ones are displayed, and if we need context, we need to visit the post. But, since comments are so disposable, of course we don't do that.

Given the edits to the answer though, I'd probably just wipe the entire thread, it's clearly not needed at this point.

Comment: Is there a good reason to also remove it from the activity history? It has happened to me that I left a definitely constructive comment, and it was gone without a trace. I started questioning my sanity the first time I saw this. It would be nice to at least be able to confirm that I did indeed leave the comment, and wasn't just dreaming. And be able to see what I said in the comment.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Comments are meant to be lightweight. Never put anything into a comment you want to keep around.  Comments (in large quantities) can actively detract from important information.  If you find yourself really needing the contents of the comment years later, it's probably better to have edited that information into the answer or the question; where it will be for all time.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Understood. In the case I remembered, I really just wanted to confirm that I had submitted the comment, and not clicked the wrong button or something. Or lost my mind. ;) And maybe see the comment one more time to try and understand why it might have been deleted, so that I can learn from it.

Comment: Its not so much 'cherry picking' but rather 'flag one comment as too chatty (easy) when its clear cut rather than flagging them all (annoying to mods apparently) or writing a custom flag (too much work? too easy to dismiss?)'

Comment: @MichaelT: I disagree about mods finding it "annoying". I've flagged entire threads many times for mods to clean up comments, and never gotten an indication that the mod was annoyed (or had a flag declined).

Comment: @KenWhite there is some guidance on [mse](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207962/could-we-have-some-consensus-on-how-to-flag-bunches-of-obsolete-comments) - and some scattered chat too.

Comment: Sorry, but one post where a single mod stated their preference does not qualify as a general statement that "mods" find them annoying. Bill (the mod in the link) did not say he "found them annoying"; he merely stated what his personal preference was, and there's no mention of annoyance or irritation or any such thing. "Some scattered chat" is as meaningful as "Someone on the internet said it was true, so it has to be".

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: *"Never put anything into a comment you want to keep around."* so in that case where exactly should you put it if it's not an answer or a question?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: "It should be edited into the post"? Are you suggesting anyone who thinks their comment is worth keeping around should go ahead and edit the answer under which they would be commenting? That seems risky. What if the answer's poster doesn't *want* the user to add that to their answer?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Er, I'm not talking about "all content", I'm ***only*** talking about the case when the person genuinely believes the comment is worth keeping around. Not sure what you mean by your second sentence? Just because something is worth keeping around doesn't mean it's appropriate to edit it into someone else's answer does it?